# Store dynamic Questions to MYSQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a question. I'm doing a PHP page that contains a section "CREATE EXAM". This will have a button that creates a question and another button inside that will create responses. The user that creates an exam will choose the number of questions and answers of the exam. After this, they must choose the correct answer of the question via checkbox.

My question is: How can I store all this in MySql?

Comment: make two separate tables for create questions and answer

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: This question is far too broad. It’s not a specific programming issue, you’re asking someone to model your database and application for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make 2 tables:

### table_name: questions

### Fields

question_id - int(11) PK 
question_text - text
question_created_datetime - datetime

### table_name: answer

### Fields

answer_id - int(11) PK 
question_id - int(11) FK 
answer_text - text 
answer_added_datetime - datetime

Comment: in answer table there will be multiple entries for one question